# Sheridan SSDB Grid set value for entire column

Tags: datagrid, vb6

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do here is possible. I've got a Sheridan SSDB Grid, which is bound to a data control. When I populate the data control, the grid gets filled.

However, I've had to manually add an additional column after populating the grid to display a value which isn't in a database table.

To do all of this, I've written this code:

```
Dim SQL As String
SQL = My_Query

dtaEmployees.DatabaseName = DB_Period_Name$
dtaEmployees.RecordSource = SQL

dtaEmployees.Refresh
dtaEmployees.Recordset.MoveFirst

grdEmployees.Redraw = True
grdEmployees.Columns.Add (4)
```

I'm not sure how I can fill this new column in, however. I've got a global variable storing the value that I need, but none of the following lines of code are working

```
grdEmployees.Columns(4).Value = My_Variable
grdEmployees.Columns(4).Text = My_Variable
```

How can I set the value for all of the rows in the grid?

*EDIT*

After following the suggestion in the comments, I've modified my code as follows.

Form load:

```
Dim dbsPeriod As Database 
Dim tdfEmployees As TableDef 
Dim fldLoop As Field 

Set dbsPeriod = OpenDatabase(DB_Period_Name$) 
Set tdfEmployees = dbsPeriod.TableDefs!Ledger

AppendDeleteField tdfEmployees, "APPEND", "Location", dbText, 8 

grdEmployees.DataSource = tdfEmployees

AppendDeleteField tdfEmployees, "DELETE", "Location"

dbsPeriod.Close
```

`AppendDeleteField` sub:

```
Private Sub AppendDeleteField(tdfTemp As TableDef, strCommand As String, _
                              strName As String, _ 
                              Optional varType, Optional varSize) 

   With tdfTemp 
    If .Updatable = False Then 
       MsgBox "Failed to initialise grid!"
       Exit Sub 
    End If 

    If strCommand = "APPEND" Then 
       .Fields.Append .CreateField(strName, varType, varSize) 
    Else 
       If strCommand = "DELETE" Then .Fields.Delete strName 
    End If 
   End With 

End Sub
```

With this code, no data is loaded into the grid at all.

Comment: What I usually do is manually add the column to the RecordSet prior to binding it to the grid.

Comment: @BrianMStafford I've not bound the data control manually, I've done it in the properties panel. Are you saying undo this then add `grid.DataBind = RecordSet` to bind it, after adding a column programatically to the record set?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  You'll need to be a little more hands on, but it's nothing too complex.

Comment: @BrianMStafford `dtaSet.RecordSet.Fields.Append(Company_Name$)` is what I've tried to do, but I get a "Data type mismatch" when I try to run the application. Am I doing it incorrectly?

Comment: The append method needs at least 2 parameters, column name and data type.  Also, try removing the parenthesis around the parameters.

Comment: @BrianMStafford `.Append strCompany, String` and `.Append(strCompany, String)` both error saying 'Expected "("'

Comment: I remember from your last question you are using DAO.  Is this still the case?  If so, check out this link to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820791.aspx),  it shows how to do what you need.

Comment: @BrianMStafford Hi, I've had a go at following this and adapting it to my code. I've added in my code to the question, no data is being returned, however.

Comment: My intent with the link was to show you the format for Fields.Append, not to necessarily use their approach.  I think your best bet is to refer to the Sheridan documentation.  It looks quite extensive and should tell you how to go about adding columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not loading the data into the `RecordSet` before you delete the field. You need to get the data (using your `SELECT` query) into a data structure which the grid can use as the `.DataSource`

A `TableDef` is not a data structure, it just allows you to make changes to the database table itself, which is why your code isn't returning any rows.